# trying to create a new entry in the address book via the ABUnknownPersonViewController on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, abaddressbook

In iOS I'm trying to create a new entry in the address book via the ABUnknownPersonViewController with this code (it's an UITableViewController):

```
- (void)                       tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *phoneNumber = [[cell textLabel] text];
    ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABMutableMultiValueRef phone =
            ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel
            (phone, phoneNumber, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel, NULL);
    bool didSet = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, phone,
            &error);

    if (!didSet) {
        return;
    }
    ABUnknownPersonViewController *viewController =
            [[[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    [viewController setUnknownPersonViewDelegate:self];
    [viewController setAllowsAddingToAddressBook:YES];
    [viewController setAllowsActions:NO];
    [viewController setDisplayedPerson:record];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
            animated:YES];
    CFRelease(record);
    CFRelease(phone);
}
```

Edit:
but it crashes apparently because the phoneNumber is formatted before is added to the address book (e.j. "987654321" becomes "987 654 321"). If I replace the phoneNumber with a constant string (@"987654321") everything runs alright. Also if I add value not for the ABPersonPhoneProperty but for ABPersonEmailProperty runs properly.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried creating a @property (copy) NSString *selectedPhoneNumber?  If you create a property, when you assign it the textLabel text, it will copy.  When next cell is selected, it will release and copy.

Comment: What do you mean by "any other string"? A constant @"string"? Any string created using [[NSString alloc] init...]?

Comment: @bryanmac assigning the copied property doesn't resolved the problem. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @H2CO3 with a constant string it works but creating it with alloc-init doesn't, not even with the convenience methods stringWith...

Comment: Try sending it a [[ retain] autorelease] message...

Comment: After you assigned the copied property, did you pass the property to AB methods?

Comment: @bryanmac yes, I replace every phoneNumber with selectedPhoneNumber

Comment: it crashes apparently because the phoneNumber is formatted before is added to the address book (e.j. "987654321" becomes "987 654 321"). If I replace the phoneNumber with a constant string (@"987654321") everything runs alright. Also if I add value not for the ABPersonPhoneProperty but for ABPersonEmailProperty runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's working while I replace:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

with:

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef phone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonEmailProperty);
```

It's not ideal but works.